# Apache Ignite throws Failed to deserialize object with given class loader on startup ( Client - Server )

Tags: java, transactions, ignite

I am trying to use custom transaction manager with ignite however it causes Failed to deserialize object with given class loader on startup.
The Transaction Manager Factory is implemented as

```
public class TransactionManagerFactory implements Factory<TransactionManager> {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private TransactionManager txMgr;

public TransactionManagerFactory(TransactionManager txMgr) {
    this.txMgr=txMgr;
}

@Override
public TransactionManager create() {
    return this.txMgr;
}
}
```

The Factory is attached to client config as following:

```
TransactionConfiguration txConfiguration=new TransactionConfiguration();
txConfiguration.setDeadlockTimeout(acquireTimeout);
txConfiguration.setDefaultTxIsolation(TransactionIsolation.READ_COMMITTED);
txConfiguration.setDefaultTxConcurrency(TransactionConcurrency.PESSIMISTIC);
txConfiguration.setTxManagerFactory(new TransactionManagerFactory(txMgr));           
this.clientConfig.setTransactionConfiguration(txConfiguration);
```

The Error says the transaction Manager itself passed to Factory is not serializable:
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.infinispan.transaction.tm.EmbeddedBaseTransactionManager

However the Transaction Manager itself should not be serializable.
How can we pass existing Transaction Manager to ignite client?

BR
Yulian Oifa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your transaction manager factory holds on to a transaction manager instance instead of creating it in `create()` method on a remote node. This is how it should work.

All non-transient fields of a serializable object must be serializable too.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer. 
Does this means that transaction would be executed on remote node? 
The goal is to reuse same transaction manager that is used by application ( for testing we use infinispan embedded , for the app itself we use wildfly transaciton manager ) for cache operations and for other operations executed by app requiring the transaction.
In case transaction would be executed on remote node we would effectively have 2 different transactions -> one local and one remote , and as result in case local transaction will rollback , remote would not...

Comment: No, the transaction is executed on a single node WRT transaction manager. But configuration still has to be serializable.

Comment: Thanks , i have tried to set the manager as transient however it did not helped.
After transactionManager.begin() local call the ignite did not saw this transaction
Local:TransactionImpl{xid=Xid{formatId=1, globalTransactionId=BC046B9DF444943A22C2BC05A84B4D110000000000000002,branchQualifier=BC046B9DF444943A22C2BC05A84B4D110000000000000002}, status=ACTIVE},Ignite:null

Where first part logs transactionManager.transaction() , and second instance.transactions().tx()

Comment: I Guess its not related to the transaction manager itself. The problem is that create is never getting called for transaction manager